# pull and push postgresql extensions error messages

Tags: postgresql, heroku

When I pull my database from heroku to localhost, I get this message :

```
▸    WARNING: Extensions in newly created target database differ from existing source database.
▸    Target extensions:
▸    
▸    Source extensions:
▸    extname
▸    ----------
▸    plpgsql
▸    unaccent
▸    (2 rows)
```

On localhost I get this:

```
select * from pg_available_extensions;
        name        | default_version | installed_version |                               comment                                
--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
 unaccent           | 1.1             |                   | text search dictionary that removes accents

(52 rows) #cut for brievity
```

BUT :

```
select * from pg_extension;
 extname | extowner | extnamespace | extrelocatable | extversion | extconfig | extcondition 
---------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------
 plpgsql |       10 |           11 | f              | 1.0        |           | 
(1 row)
```

And on heroku:

```
DATABASE=> select * from pg_extension;
 extname  | extowner | extnamespace | extrelocatable | extversion | extconfig | extcondition 
----------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------
 plpgsql  |       10 |           11 | f              | 1.0        |           | 
 unaccent |       10 |      5147991 | t              | 1.1        |           | 
(2 rows)
```

So I guess the question is how to activate `unaccent` locally. The other question is: why do I get this message on `plpgsql`?

Comment: please update your ticket with `select * from pg_extension` and check if you run it against right database (not postgres or template eg)